# Working with a non-default package explorer structure in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently decided to help a friend out with some minor UI stuff on an app he's working on. It turns out he doesn't use Eclipse at all and just codes and builds (using Ant) straight out of a command line. I, on the other hand, wouldn't consider myself a master at android yet so I mostly rely on Eclipse. This seems to have caused a bit of a problem, though. The directory for the app he built is structured this way:

```
Project
    (dir)android
    (dir)java
    (dir)native
    (file)patch
    (file)README
```

android, java, and native are directories while patch and README are just files. The android directory is where all the stuff I'm used to working with, app-wise, is located (src, res, AndroidManifest, etc). From what I'm told, the other 2 directories simply have files that are used by the android directory (classes, libs, scripts, etc).

Personally, I don't like how his is structured but I don't want to change it since this isn't my app. I WOULD like to get it to work with eclipse, though. Ideally, it would be nice to have the Package Explorer structure be completely the same. Importing "Project" doesn't do this, though. It only detects the "android" directory (I'm guessing because it's the only one with an AndroidManifest file). I thought about importing the other directories along with it or creating linked resources but none of these seem to work.

I HAVE been able to import the project into eclipse as a general project and editing the .project file to make it an android application. The problem then is that I can't run it. It complains that there is no AndroidManifest and project.properties file in the root "Project" directory.

As you might be able to tell, I've been at this for a while but can't get anything to work. Can anyone out there suggest a way to accomplish this? Or maybe add on to what I've already tried? Any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the project like you are doing, and then import-> general-> file system,  select the other folders you want to import and select the project as the destination. That should do it.